# How to reset bluetooth that stopped working on a Linux laptop? (after resuming from standby)

Tags: linux, bluetooth, usb-device

### Context:

- Linux kernel 5.10.x (5.18.x also)
- Thinkpad X1c (gen7) laptop

### Problem:

Sometimes, when I set my system to sleep (suspend to RAM) and then resume, **the bluetooth adapter is not found anymore**. If I reboot, it works again.

### When it works,

here is the (internal) bluetooth adapter as seen from `lsusb`:

```
# lsusb | grep 8087 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
```

And I'm able to scan, connect & use my bluetooth devices.

### When it doesn't work:

- usually after a computer power suspend/resume (not systematically),
- **`lsusb` does not display the above device anymore**,
- I'm not able to scan, connect or even see my bluetooth adapter.

And `kern.log` says:

```
usb usb1-port10: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad? 
usb usb1-port10: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad? 
usb usb1-port10: attempt power cycle
usb 1-10: new low-speed USB device number 71 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-10: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-10: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-10: device not accepting address 71, error -71
usb 1-10: new low-speed USB device number 72 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-10: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-10: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-10: device not accepting address 72, error -71
usb usb1-port10: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Port 10 is the one connected to the bluetooth adapter.

### What I already tried (doesn't work):

- `systemctl restart bluetooth.service`,
- `modprobe -r btusb && modprobe btusb`,
- `bluetoothctl power on`: says `No default controller available`,
- `rfkill unblock bluetooth`, even if it shows a bluetooth device and accepts the command.

### My question

**How can I make the Bluetooth work properly again without rebooting the whole computer?**

Answer (score 12):

May be overkill, but does actually work:

- **resetting the whole USB "Bus"** to which the bluetooth adapter is hardwired.

### Solution (see warning below)

Get the PCI ID of Bus 1 "root hub" (don't know why the error):

```
# lsusb -v -s1:1 | grep iSerial
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
```

And use it to **unbind** (will disconnect all related USB devices) and re-**bind**, as root (`su`, `sudo -i`, `sudo bash -c "..."`):

```bash
echo -n '0000:00:14.0' >| /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind && \
sleep 3 && \
echo -n '0000:00:14.0' >| /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
```

***Beware,*** all my (internal & external) USB devices are connected to this hub: external mouse, external keyboard, internal webcam, internal fingerprint sensor... All **will be (temporarily) disconnected** in the process.

### Result

After that `kern.log` says:

```
usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0aaa, bcdDevice= 0.02
usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[...]
Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 42 week 52 2015
[...]
Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1643271 usecs
Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 13788 usecs
```

And `lsusb | grep 8087`:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp.
```

And it is possible to use the bluetooth again!

### Another way?

While it's better than rebooting, **do you know another solution that would be less "intrusive"?**

Comment: Months that I have this problem, and this seems the only way to solve it. One liner may work even better since you want to have both lines run in "single shot" as you lose mouse & keyboard. Something like `sudo bash -c "..." ` ?

Comment: @user3041539 I added some sort of one liner

Comment: awesome! that one liner is much better, I'd even say to hide the few lines solution so a a user doesn't hit with non functioning peripheries

Comment: I would even request the warning before the snippet. I started to type it, from a search engine preview, and almost ran it before seeing the warning.

Comment: @mcint I added (see warning below) in the section title to make it more visible

Comment: Appreciated! 'twas a bit of a nit request. Using this often now.

Comment: FWIW, this also works for me on my X1 Carbon Gen 8. It happens rarely, and I usually just reboot, but I was in the middle of something and this saved me.